# Cypress.io - What is the use case for {esc} sequence of type function where is it useful?

Tags: cypress

What's the purpose of {esc} sequence and how to use it?

[Cypress.io doc -> api -> type -> arguments section {esc} sequence](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Arguments)

Comment: It just Types the Escape key, like other buttons enter , backspace .

Comment: One common use case would be when you click on a search input there may be suggestions pop up or when it may try to autocomplete. Escape button can exit out of those.